# React JS selector with fetch

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, selector

When I take data from this form via fetch by name for selector, I get id=1 or 2 in the data transfer, but I want to get name ="Name1" or "Name2". It works with regular forms, but not with the selector

```
 type Service = {
        id: number,
        name: string,
    }
    
    const serviceList: Service[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Name1',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Name2',
        }
      const [curIdService, setСurIdService] = useState(0)
      async function post(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
      const serviceName = event.target.curIdService.value
      const res = await fetch('urlApi', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ serviceName  })
        })
        if (res.ok) {
            const result = await res.json()
            console.log(result);            
        }
      }

       

    return (
    <>
     <form id="submit-form" onSubmit={post}>
       <select className="selectModel" value={curIdService} name="curIdService" onChange={event => 
      setСurIdService(+event.target.value)} >
           <option value={0} selected disabled>Выберите вид услуг</option>{serviceList.map(service => 
          <option key={service.id} value={service.id}>{service.name}</option>)}
       </select>
     </form>
    </>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you're passing allong `service.id`:

```
<option key={service.id} value={service.id}>{service.name}</option>
```

Change it to

```
<option key={service.id} value={service.name}>{service.name}</option>
```

Comment: the problem is that when I did this, the following selects stopped working for me, which are related by nesting level . have 3 selects, one is an array element by id (service name), inside it ( services of this service), and this is all connected by id{
        id: 1,
        nameService: 'string',
        typeOfService: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'string',
                price: 500,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'string',
                price: 1000,}

Comment: 1)<select className="selectModel" value={curIdService} name="curIdService" onChange={event => setСurIdService(+event.target.value)} >
                        <option value={0} selected disabled>first SELECT</option>
                        {serviceList.map(service => <option key={service.id} value={service.id}>{service.name}</option>)}
                    </select>

Comment: 2) <select className="selectModel" value={typeOfServicelId} name="typeOfServicelId" onChange={event => setTypeOfServicelId(+event.target.value)}>
                        <option value={0} selected disabled>SECOND SELECT</option>
                        {serviceList.find(service => service.id === curIdService)?.typeOfService.map(type => <option key={type.id} value={type.id}>{type.name}</option>)}

Comment: @XAZGНеизвестный Please make an edit to your answer and add this new code with an explanation of what it is. In the comments this format is very hard to read.